# Can Robot Framework run remain keywords if running keyword is failed?

Tags: robotframework

Now, If I runs Robot Framework and some keyword failed, It will stop and not run remaining keywords. So, Can I set critical or not in the keyword? If the keyword is not critical, It will failed test case but run remaining keywords until finish test case.

Example of Code:
*** Test Cases ***
Test Google Search
---- Open Web Browser
---- Input Google URL
---- Input Text
---- Click Search

and if keyword "Input Google URL" Failed, Can it run "Input Text" and "Click Search" keywords?

Comment: Answer is yes but it does not make sense. `Input Text` will fail as it wont find the given xpath on the page. you can use `Run Keyword And Ignore Error     Input google URL`

Comment: Does the built-in keyword [Run keyword and continue on failure](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Continue%20On%20Failure) do what you want?